# using the wso2 carbon registry to store configuration data for SOA services

Tags: wso2

I have a number of different SOA services that use different approaches for storing configuration data for the service.  For example the configuration data is stored in database tables, property files, and jndi.

I would like to standardize my approach to storing configuration data.  Is the carbon registry an acceptable place to store all the configuration data for my services?

Can I just store this data directly in the carbon registry, or should I be looking to just use the WSO2 Governance Registry for this data?

What does WSO2 Governance Registy give me that is not provided by directly using the carbon registry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> " Is the carbon registry an acceptable place to store all the
>   configuration data for my services?"

The best practice would be,
Store the Resource Metadata in Registry and run-time data in a database.

> Is the carbon registry an acceptable place to store all the
>   configuration data for my services?"

Yes, you can store the configurations in the registry. Generally, configurations will be stored in the config space, and the resources which are having governance aspect will go to governance registry space

> "What does WSO2 Governance Registry give me that is not provided by
>   directly using the carbon registry?

- Store, manage and search any kind of enterprise asset, including services, APIs, policies, projects or applications. You can extend the predefined asset metadata or create your own
- Navigate through assets using taxonomies
- Access and manage assets via a REST API, supporting the integration with enterprise initiative such as DevOps
- Describe relationships between assets such as dependencies, usage or associations and perform impact analysis
- Attach custom life cycle to assets and engage custom actions when an asset transitions from one state to the next
- Secure the access to assets via a fine-grained permission model
- Leverage social tools such as ratings and comments to enable better communication between asset providers and consumers
- Notify users of any asset changes via email or a notification system of your choice
- Integrate with mediation engines such as WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus or others via UDDI and REST for dynamic discovery of services and APIs endpoints

**There are plenty of advantages of using G-Reg, To see the full list please find this [post](http://www.soagovernance.org/2016/08/soa-governance-with-wso2-governance.html) or [offcial G-Reg page](http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/).**

Comment: thanks for the response.  To clarify, by run time data you mean business domain data?

Comment: Yes, eg: request/response related data